# MySQL installation:rpm vs source

Tags: mysql, installation

I installed MySQL by rpm before:

```
[root@jiaoyou sphinx-0.9.9-rc2]# rpm -aq|grep -i mysql
MySQL-devel-community-5.1.34-0.rhel5.x86_64
MySQL-server-community-5.1.34-0.rhel5.x86_64
MySQL-client-community-5.1.34-0.rhel5.x86_64
```

And now I need to install it from source code:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.37.tar.gz/from/pick
```

Will it install all the three above with source or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the source code, with the default options will install mysql libraries and mysql server.

[MySQL Source Installation Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/quick-install.html)

Comment: @HD,I'm also reading this page,but didn't see where it says "with the default options will install mysql libraries and mysql server"?

Comment: In the configure options you can find "without-server" is not a default http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/configure-options.html.